# How to split a text consisting of 18000 sentences into chunks

Tags: python, string

How can I split a text consisting of 18000 sentences into chunks, each one should contain 2000 sentences (more or less).

I know how to split a text into equal chunks by characters, however this is not what I need:

```
s = "Wrap a single paragraph of text, returning a list of wrapped lines. Reformat the single paragraph in 'text' so it fits in lines of n more than 'width' columns, and return a list of wrapped lines."
list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter(s)]*2)))
```

Comment: How do you define a sentence?

Comment: You can split your text by ('.') as a first step

Comment: @balderman. Splited by dots `.`

Comment: @IoaTzimas: Sure, but what's next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
l=s.split('.')
res={}
for i in range(len(l)//2000+1):
    res[i]=l[i:i+2000]
```

Comment: I think that I may loose some part of text in this case. No?

Comment: Sry, i have updated the code. All text will now be included

Answer (score 1):

Slice the list into chunks

```
SLICE_SIZE = 3 #TODO modify per your needs
doc = '''Hello python.Bon.jack.jim.summit.How can I split a text consisting of 18000 sentences into chunks, each one should contain 2000 sentences (more or less).
I know how to split a text into equal chunks by characters, however this is not what I need.Note that these methods are looked up on the type (metaclass) of a class. They cannot be defined as class methods in the actual class. This is consistent with the lookup of special methods that are called on instances, only in this case the instance is itself a class'''

chunks = []
parts = doc.split('.')
reminder = len(parts) % SLICE_SIZE
chunks_count = int((len(parts) - reminder) / SLICE_SIZE)
for x in range(chunks_count):
    chunks.append(parts[x * SLICE_SIZE: (x+1) * SLICE_SIZE])
if reminder:
    chunks.append(parts[-reminder:])
print(chunks)
```